# show angularjs dropdown selected value

Tags: angularjs, ajax

I am adding employee with designation field in dropdown (say 'Employee'). When I try to edit the profile of employee in another page the designation should display the pre-selected dropdown value with remaining values below.(the selected designation is not displaying first. it is shown as normal dropdown)
I have tried `selected="selected"`

```
<select class="form-control edited" id="designation_edit"  name="designation_edit" ng-model="designation_edit">
       <option value="HR" selected="selected">HR Executive</option>
       <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
       <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
       <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
</select>
```

I have two modal boxes in my page. One for "add employee" and another for `edit profile`. When I add an employee with designation value from drop-down as `employee`, this selected value should be displayed first in edit page 'designation' drop-down with remaining values in the dropdown. 
But currently, it is showing as normal dropdown in edit profile page. I need to fetch the selected value from add page and display here.

Help me to come out with this in angularjs.

Is it correct to add the below line in ajax call

```
$('#designation_edit').attr("selected":"selected");
```

I have tried:

```
$('#designation_edit').append('Designation Manager Employee Admin');
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple way

If you have a Users as response or a Array/JSON you defined, First You need to set the selected value in controller, then you put the same model name in html. This example i wrote to explain in easiest way.
Simple example
**Inside Controller:**

```
$scope.Users = ["Suresh","Mahesh","Ramesh"]; 
$scope.selectedUser = $scope.Users[0];
```

**Your HTML**

```
<select data-ng-options="usr for usr in Users" data-ng-model="selectedUser">
</select>
```

**complex example
Inside Controller:**

```
$scope.JSON = {
       "ResponseObject":
           [{
               "Name": "Suresh",
               "userID": 1
           },
           {
               "Name": "Mahesh",
               "userID": 2
           }]
   };
   $scope.selectedUser = $scope.JSON.ResponseObject[0];
```

**Your HTML**

```
<select data-ng-options="usr.Name for usr in JSON.ResponseObject" data-ng-model="selectedUser"></select>
<h3>You selected: {{selectedUser.Name}}</h3>
```

Comment: The dropdown is appearing as normal. The selected value in add page is not displaying

Answer (score 1):

To show selected value you can do as follows

#### Controller

assign a default value to the ng-model

```
 $scope.empDesignationMapping = {
     employee1 : "manager",
     employee2 : "HR",
     employee3: "Admin"
 }
$scope.designation_edit = $scope.empDesignationMapping[employee1] // should be dynamic employee
```

#### HTML

```
<select ng-model="designation_edit" ng-selected="designation_edit" >
```

after that whenever you select something something it will show as selected.

Comment: I have tried with this but it is displaying the selected value as "manager" for all other employees selected with other designation types. What shall I do to overcome this?

Comment: form a hashObject (key-value pair) like `{ employee : designation }`

whenever you get the employee pass it to hashObject[employee] you will get your designation

Comment: Can't able to get.. Can u explain how to?

Comment: I have edited  my answer above, can you please check that and tell me what you needed.

Comment: I have already added an employee as HR , but his designation is shown as "Manager" selected. I have tried with your answer.

Comment: you have to pass employee1/2/3 in dynamic to the mapping.
If you pass employee type dynamically you will get that dynamic designation. you are missing that.
For further discussion please post your code here either fiddle/plunkr
we will solve it.

Comment: <select class="form-control edited" ng-model="designation_edit" ng-selected="designation_edit">    <option value="HR" selected="selected">HR Executive</option>
                                                      <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                                                      <option value="Employee">Employee</option>
                                                      <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                                             </select>

Comment: Hi, I tried the solution you mentioned. It is not yet displaying the actual selected value in dropdown which I selected while adding employee.